# Cannot read specific values in GROUP_CONCAT result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySql database and in one of my queries i use the GROUP_CONCAT function to get values from individual rows as a string separated by commas. Initially, the query was returning BLOB and as someone suggested in another question i changed the GROUP_CONCAT to GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(classes.type, CHAR(2))). So far so good. The query works and i can see in phpMyAdmin the values separated by commas in the result set.
The call.type field used in GROUP_CONCAT  can have only "1" or "2" as value. So the results are something like "1" - "1,2" - "2" - "1,2" (dash separates result here) etc.
The problem is that i cannot read specifically the character "2" using php. I have tried everything, strpos, in_array (after using explode). For example strpos returns the position of the character when i use strpos($result,"1") but always returns 0 when i use strpos($result,"2").
Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried print the string character by character? What is the encoding of the `CONVERT`ed strings? Like `for($i=...) var_dump($result[$i]);`

Comment: The first result of the query is "2,1" as i see in phpMyAdmin. var_dump($result) returns string(3) "2,1" while var_dump($result) with for returns string(1) "2" string(1) "," string(1) "1"  for the same result. The encoding is UTF-8

Comment: By the way, if($result[$i] == 2) works when i read the result character by character

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the code? There may be an easier way to write it altogether, but I'm having trouble understanding what it is that you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the position of the given integer within the returned list of comma separated integers?